# Oracle SQL Developer syntax 'use database' like as MSSQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I use in query SQL file from Oracle SQL Developer, syntax like as MSSQL "USE DATABSE GO" for direct connect to an Oracle database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle introduced the multitenant Database in version 12c. It's structured similar to a MSSQL instance. If you are in that version, you can switch between pluggable databases with the following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET container = pdb1;
```

If you are on 11g or previous or on a non-cbo 12c Database, I don't see the way to switch to another instance.

Comment: Thanks, but now I use 11g version.

Comment: Ok, so changing database means changing instance, so you need (AFAIK) a new connection and re-login. I don't see a way to do it.